# JAAS login configuration error on Tomcat. Unable to loas JAAS config file

Tags: java, tomcat, jaas

I am trying to implement a simple JAAS module with realm configuration on Tomcat 7. I am trying to implement this based on the following link:

http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/jaas-authentication-in-tomcat-example

I have placed jass.config in CATALINA_HOME/conf folder and have added the following code to CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.bat file

```
JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS "-Djava.security.auth.login.config==$CATALINA_HOME/conf/jaas.config"
```

However, once I start Tomcat and attempt to access the protected admin.html page, I get the basic login dialog of the browser (as expected). But while trying to log in, Tomcat reports the following error:

```
SEVERE: Unexpected error
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration
```

Please help how to make Tomcat find the JAAS config file.

Comment: @Vladimír Schäfer Thanks for your quick response. I am in a Windows 8 environment. Based on your suggestion, I updated **<CATALINA_HOME>/bin/catalina.bat** with your startup option. I also explicitly set the environment variable CATALINA_HOME to **E:\apache-tomcat-7.0.55.** Still the issue persist. Is there a specific section in catalina.bat where I should add your suggested startup option?

Comment: Could it be a typo - in your question you have "jass.config" in text, but "jaas.config" in parameter - notice the amount of 's'? If this doesn't help try removing the "%CATALINA_HOME% altogether and specify full path to the file in the catalina.bat and see if it helps.

Comment: I finally added jaas.config to the root directory of the Web app in the same level of the WEB-INF, META-INF, com\byteslounge\jaas package directory.  com\byteslounge\jaas contains the login module class along with the user and role Principal classes. I have updated Catalina.bat with the full path to the current location of jaas.config. jass.config is getting located but the login module is not getting identified. The error is 'javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: unable to find LoginModule class: com.byteslounge.jaas.BytesLoungeLoginModule'. Where I am going wrong here?

Comment: You may have to put the LoginModule to the Tomcat's classpath, i.e. to tomcat/lib

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you're using `.bat` file suggests you're using Windows where variables get referred to using `%VARIABLE%` notation instead of `$VARIABLE`. Try changing the expression to:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.security.auth.login.config=%CATALINA_HOME%/conf/jaas.config
```